# How to build the UISlider automatic slide by itself in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

In purpose, I want to set the `UISlider` will auto slide by self to use in video player.
I try to find the solution by research and follow that code, but it's still not work. Everyone have any solution with this here is my code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
      self.sldTime.maximumValue = 10
      self.sldTime.minimumValue = 0
      self.sldTime.continuous = true
      self.sldTime.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderAutoChange), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

func sliderAutoChange() {
    let index = Float(self.sldTime.value + 1)   // increase by 1
    self.sldTime.setValue(index, animated: false)
    print("index \(index)")
}
```

When I debug it, it seem like the **sliderAutoChange()** function do not call.

Comment: User timer for changes a value of your silder

Comment: `sliderAutoChange` will only be called when the user changes the slider.

Comment: ramddy, Moradiya Thank for replay, and how to set it auto slide /.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change `Slider` value automatically then you can use `NSTimer` like this.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.sldTime.maximumValue = 10
    self.sldTime.minimumValue = 0
    self.sldTime.continuous = true

    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateSlider(_:), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)      
}

func updateSlider(timer: NSTimer) {

    let index = Float(self.sldTime.value + 1)   // increase by 1
    self.sldTime.setValue(index, animated: true)
    print("index \(index)")
    if self.sldTime.value >= self.sldTime.maximumValue {
          timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect Thank, It's work and save my time. Thank to fast Answer :)

Comment: I suggest you change the `if` condition to be `>=` just incase there is any roundoff error.